# HTML range input min value not working as expected

Tags: html, angular, range

I've used HTML range input in my Angular 7 code and set it's min and max values to 69 and 200. I want my slider to begin from 69 instead of 0. But now user can slide back to 0. Below is my simple HTML code:

```
<input formControlName="SealHeight" [(ngModel)]="seal_height" type="range" min="min_height" max="200" class="slider-color">
```

Below is the screenshot of how it looks like:

[image: Screenshot of range picker]

I need that range picker should not show below 69. So that user can not go below mentioned min limit. Thanks!

Comment: Try to look [HERE](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Brange%5D)

Comment: Issue is that I'm giving min height as a number int, while it need it as a string. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try sample code in html editor

```
<input type="range" onchange="this.setAttribute('value',this.value);" min="69" max="200" step="1" value="69" />
```

Answer (score 1):

set a proper `min` for it:

```
<input formControlName="SealHeight" [(ngModel)]="seal_height" type="range" min="69" max="200" class="slider-color">
```